# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "testingland_mapcafes" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

So I am having major Postgres/Django dramas. I kept getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "testingland_mapcafes" does not exist
```

I tried deleting migrations cache, checking and rechecking `make migrations`, running `python3 manage.py migrate testingland zero` and then running `migrate`

I have no idea what is going wrong when I check tables in PSQL (db is called `vygr`) i see the following:

```
Schema |            Name            | Type  |    Owner
--------+----------------------------+-------+--------------
 public | auth_group                 | table | x
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | x
 public | auth_permission            | table | x
 public | auth_user                  | table | x
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | x
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | x
 public | django_admin_log           | table | x
 public | django_content_type        | table | x
 public | django_migrations          | table | x
 public | django_session             | table | x
 public | spatial_ref_sys            | table | x
```

My settings.py are set up like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'vygr',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Here is the model in question which does exist but not as a table in my db (yet?):

```
class mapCafes(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image_embed = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cafe_name
```

Here is the traceback

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, testingland
Running migrations:
  Applying testingland.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "testingland_mapcafes" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 229, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 115, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "testingland_mapcafes" does not exist
```

Here is migration 0001_initial.py:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.7 on 2021-07-07 10:12

from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthGroup',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_group',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthGroupPermissions',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_group_permissions',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthPermission',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('codename', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_permission',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthUserGroups',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_user_groups',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='AuthUserUserPermissions',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_user_user_permissions',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DjangoAdminLog',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('action_time', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('object_id', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('object_repr', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('action_flag', models.SmallIntegerField()),
                ('change_message', models.TextField()),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'django_admin_log',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DjangoContentType',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('app_label', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('model', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'django_content_type',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DjangoMigrations',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('app', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('applied', models.DateTimeField()),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'django_migrations',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DjangoSession',
            fields=[
                ('session_key', models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('session_data', models.TextField()),
                ('expire_date', models.DateTimeField()),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'django_session',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='mapCafes',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('cafe_name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('cafe_address', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('cafe_long', models.FloatField()),
                ('cafe_lat', models.FloatField()),
                ('geolocation', django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField(blank=True, geography=True, null=True, srid=4326)),
                ('venue_type', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('source', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('description', models.CharField(max_length=1000)),
                ('image_embed', models.CharField(max_length=10000)),
            ],
            options={
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserList',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('list_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Venues',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('venue_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('venue_address', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('venue_long', models.FloatField(null=True)),
                ('venue_lat', models.FloatField(null=True)),
                ('venue_geolocation', django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField(blank=True, geography=True, null=True, srid=4326)),
                ('user_list', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='testingland.userlist')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='VenueList',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('venue_name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='VenueComments',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('comment', models.CharField(max_length=10000)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('venue', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='testingland.mapcafes')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserConnections',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('followed', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='followers', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('follower', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='following', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='suggestion',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('venue_name', models.CharField(max_length=500)),
                ('venue_address', models.CharField(max_length=1000)),
                ('venue_type', models.CharField(max_length=500)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ReplyComments',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('reply_comment', models.CharField(max_length=10000)),
                ('original_comment', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='testingland.venuecomments')),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PromotionCampaign',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('promo_title', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('promo_quantity', models.IntegerField()),
                ('promo_venue', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='testingland.mapcafes')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='liked',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('liked_venue', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='testingland.mapcafes')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='feedback',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('feedback_type', models.CharField(max_length=500)),
                ('feedback_content', models.CharField(max_length=10000)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserVenue',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('user_list', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='testingland.userlist')),
                ('venue', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='testingland.mapcafes')),
            ],
            options={
                'unique_together': {('user_list', 'venue')},
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please show the code for the migration file `testingland.0001_initial`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, added to OP

Comment: Uhh, wait  why do you have `managed = False` on your models if their tables don't exist yet and you are expecting the migration system to actually manage them?

Comment: I had dropped an old DB and was trying to migrate these over to a new one. So will that be the problem?

Comment: Can you describe what _exactly_ did you do? That is not how you are supposed to copy data over, you can simply use `dumpdata` and `loaddata` management commands to do that, or you can go for some solution that your database offers for backups etc.

Comment: I was having an ongoing problem with my old database, repeatedly getting ``django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "x" does not exist
`` when trying to run migrations. Following some advice on previous SO questions I dropped the DB in PSQL and created a new one, changed the ``settings`` file, commented out my ``views.py`` and ``urls`` and tried running migrations to set up my models into tables in new DB from django. Previous DB had some tables I hadn't created in Django. (Learning as I go)